# Requesting a API token with both basic authentication and application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: api, token, webapi

I'm trying to create an application using MS Visual Studio in either vb.net or C# to receive a token for a web api that has both basic authentication and application/x-www-form-urlencoded. When I send the request from Postman the requested works. Please see Postman screen shots below. When is use the below code I receive and message "Request failed with status code NotFound" back and the request fails. Can any point in the the right direction to resolve this.

Thank you

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWgXh.png)
[postman body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNvH2.png)

`private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        Uri baseurl = new Uri("https://api address/token");
        RestClient client = new RestClient(baseurl);

        //client.Timeout = -1;
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("post", Method.Post);
        
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic M2U4Y");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials",true);
        request.AddParameter("scope", "https://?????????",true);
        RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        if (response.Content == "")
        {
            textBox1.Text = response.ErrorException.Message ;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = response.Content;
        }
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. With the below code.

```
    Uri baseurl = new Uri("https://api address/token");
    RestClient client = new RestClient(baseurl);
  
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(baseurl, Method.Post);
    
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic M2U4Y");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https://FED0C291",arameterType.RequestBody);RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    if (response.Content == "")
    {
        textBox1.Text = response.ErrorException.Message ;
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text = response.Content;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).